# Mongoose findById correct way to check users rights

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to check users rights to protect route.
I finding user by Id from token, and check in DB "admin" field.
It finds and check well, but i don't get what to do next. I'm using this middleware in "/admin" route:

```
User.findById(decodedToken.userId,)
.then(user =>{
    isAdmin = user.admin;
    if(!isAdmin){
        const error = new Error('Unauthorized')
        error.statusCode = 401
        throw error
    }else{
        req.userId = decodedToken.userId
        next();
    }
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
    return err
})
```

but I don't get any response on frontend, only pending GET request

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a response to your frontend:

```
router.route("/").get((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    User.findById(decodedToken.userId, )
        .then(user => {
            //your logic
            res.end('Have Permission');
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            return err
        })
})
```

If you want to send an object you can do `res.json(yourobject)`

Comment: I have added next(err) in the catch block, and now I get authorization logic to work. Is it correct?:
`User.findById(decodedToken.userId,)
    .then(user =>{
        isAdmin = user.admin;
        if(!isAdmin){
            const error = new Error('Не авторизованный доступ')
            error.statusCode = 401
            throw error
        }else{
            req.userId = decodedToken.userId
            next();
        }
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        next(err)
    })`